# Migrating WP website to Google Cloud & DNS propagating - Cloudflare

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, cloudflare, google-cloud-dns

So, I have migrated my WP website from my shared hosting to google cloud servers. I've set up the static ip address, and edited my current A type record on cloudflare to that static IP address and CNAME record to my domain name. After a couple of hours I've tried to secure my website via an SSL certificate, via the SSH tool at google cloud, but it says:

```
Warning: The domain 'mydomain.com' resolves to a different IP address than 
the one detected for this machine, which is 'mystaticip'. Please fix its DNS 
entries or remove it.
```

How do I know if the new DNS records are applied or not? Is there a tool or something? When I go to my domain I can open the website. Not secured, but it works. How can I know if it is launching from my old hosting or from google cloud?

[image]

Comment: Switch from `Proxied` to `DNS only` and then  setup your certificate. Enable `Proxied` after SSL is working correctly. Note: this issue will raise its head again when it is time to renew the certificate.

Comment: Thanks! What to do when the issue raises again?

Comment: Follow the same steps. Your question does not shows exactly what you are doing. I am assuming you are using a Google Managed SSL certificate. There are other options such as Let's Encrypt and purchasing a certificate. In any event, you will have this problem again when it comes time to renew the certificate as the DNS settings must match the domain name/machine address. Cloudflare proxies, which means there is a proxy in the middle.

Comment: Can I set up an auto-renew ssl?

Comment: And one more question. What should I do with those IPs starting with 69.90.x.x for cpanel, webdisk, webmail and so on? Should I just delete those A records?

Comment: SSL certificates do not "auto-renew". Either a person/company, program or process is involved to "renew" SSL certificates. In reality, an SSL certificate is not renewed, it is replaced with a new certificate.

Comment: In regards to cpanel, etc. I cannot answer. No details. Create one question asking one item. Create additional questions for each question.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what John said, you have to set it up first to `DNS only`, then you can check the records using [this](https://dnschecker.org/) website.

For a more detailed information, you may want to check [this](https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/) instead.

Check if the IP is resolved from the old host or the Google IP: `35.x.x.x`.

Comment: Thanks! And what about the auto-renew ssl? Will that work?